# Is there any invalid character for fields?

Tags: google-analytics

My site's encoding is UTF-8. Is there any invalid character for text fields?

All characters are acceptable?

Ex. emoji or ¥n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to send as an event: an emoji and the two special characters you wrote.

This is the result in Google Analytics:

[image]

Google Analytics allows those characters.